# pip install requests[security] NameError: name 'python_implementation' is not defined

Tags: python, pip, vagrant, virtualenv

I am having an issue while running `pip install requests[security]==2.10.0`.

I am running this in a `virtualenv` on a `bento/debian-7.8` with `Python 2.7.3`.

Here is the error:

```
Collecting cryptography>=1.9 (from pyOpenSSL>=0.13->requests[security]==2.10.0->-r requirements.txt (line 22))
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 561, in _prepare_file
    set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2774, in extras
    return [dep for dep in self._dep_map if dep]
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2797, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2830, in _compute_dependencies
    common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2827, in reqs_for_extra
    if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
  File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/_markerlib/markers.py", line 113, in marker_fn
    return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
  File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python_implementation' is not defined
```

Comment: What version of pip do you have?  If it's anything other than the latest (9.0.1), upgrade it and try again.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the pip version. pip --version == 9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely caused by an outdated pip version inside your virtualenv. Try upgrading it with the following command:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: You should also upgrade `setuptools` (Python 2.7.3 is really old).

Comment: The issue does not seem to be the pip version. This was working until recently. Not sure why.

Comment: Updating setuptools did not help.